# How does spring-boot able to serve specific url?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-boot, servlet-3.0

**In my previous experience:**

- When using pure `servlet`, we define servlets so that it will serve requests that match specific urls.
- When using `struts2`, we define a filter so that it will serve requests that match specific urls.
- When using `springMVC` in a traditional xml configuration style, we define a dispatcher servlet so that it will serve requests that match specific urls.

**But with `spring-boot`:**

Seems no servlet or filter is defined explicitly. But it still could serve specific urls.

**The questions is:**

- Is it still using servlet? If yes, how it get to serve urls without defining servlet or filter explicitly?

---

**Additional related questions** *(base on tips from comments)*:

- It seems the implementation of `SpringBootServletInitializer` will be invoked on deploy, but who is going to invoke it?

Comment: Yes, it's still using a DispatcherServlet.

Comment: @JBNizet Can you tell where it defines the servlet? I check `SpringApplication` and `SpringBootServletInitializer` roughly, but didn't get a clue.

Comment: SpringBootServletInitializer implements [WebApplicationInitializer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html?is-external=true), and the javadoc of this interface explains how that works.

Comment: @JBNizet Very nice, didn't aware there is a `ServletContext.addServlet()` API from servlet 3.0+. I got another doubt base on your tips, who is going to invoke `SpringBootServletInitializer`'s implementation? I updated the question can you also help with that, thanks.

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping the community - asking/editing sub-questions is just confusing for others. Please create a new question.

Comment: Again, this is explained in the javadoc: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer.html

Comment: @BrianClozel I removed the irrelevant parts, so that to make it make sense for other readers. I asked this in the same question because I feel they are very related, and it's beneficial for the reader too I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39214547/2816631) in details, on startup, **while initializing an embedded server** (Tomcat by default), Spring Boot **creates and registers** `DispatcherServlet` as a servlet.

Spring then, as usual, **scans your own classes** (including the one you invoke `SpringApplication.run()` from) and sets corresponding mapping for your controllers, if you have any. For example mapping for `/hello` here:

```
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class TestSpring {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    String hello() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(TestSpring.class, args);
    }

}
```