# spring-boot - Which piece of code actually register dispatcher servlet for springMVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to find out in `spring-boot`, which implementation of `WebApplicationInitializer` actually register the dispatcher servlet.

I didn't found any piece code from `SpringBootServletInitializer` or its parent types did that.

Instead, `AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer` does the job, but it's abstract, I can't find any of its concrete implementation with help of Eclipse.

So, which piece of code from which class is actually invoked to register the dispatcher servlet for springMVC?

*This is a subsequent question of: [How does spring-boot able to serve specific url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39192943/how-does-spring-boot-able-to-serve-specific-url)*

Comment: Please, show your Spring Boot start method and annotations.

Comment: @ArtemNovikov It's very similar as in https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Below is the description of Spring Boot initialization steps that eventually register `DispatcherServlet`.

### Example Code

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class TestSpring {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(TestSpring.class, args);
    }
}
```

### Spring Boot Initialization Steps

Here are the steps:

1. `SpringApplication.run()` creates `EmbeddedWebApplicationContext` application context;
2. Calls its `refresh()` method;
3. Refresh process reads annotations of the starting class `TestSpring`. It looks for import annotations. `EnableAutoConfiguration` is one of them. For an import annotation the refresh process gets the corresponding class from the annotation `value` and invokes its `selectImports()` method;
4. In case of `@EnableAutoConfiguration` the corresponding class is `EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector` whose `selectImports()` loads tons of other import selectors from the `META-INF/spring.factories`;
5. This process continues recursively. Also, all bean definitions, that are inside these import selectors, are read. I.e. it includes beans defined by a method with the `@Bean` annotation, i.e. beans that require the Spring context to call the corresponding method automatically to instantiate them;
6. The `resfresh()` continues and reaches `onRefresh()`, the `createEmbeddedServletContainer()` method is called inside;
7. Among read bean defitions at the previous step, beans implementing `ServletContextInitializer` are searched for and instantiated. One of them is the bean, defined by the `DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DispatcherServletRegistrationConfiguration#dispatcherServletRegistration()` method of `ServletRegistrationBean` type that extends `ServletContextInitializer`. As you can guess from the name of the class, such initializers add a given servlet (in this case **DispatcherServlet**) to a given `ServletContext`, when their `onStartup()` method is invoked;
8. A tomcat embedded server is created (not started completely yet). All found `ServletContextInitializer`s at the previous step are passed to this tomcat initialization - **this is where the `onStartup()` methods of those `ServletContextInitializer`s are called and `DispatcherServlet` gets created and registered as servlet**;
9. End of `onRefresh()` of application context;
10. The `finishRefresh()` is called where tomcat is finally started by `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start()`;
11. End of `refresh()` of application context and other final initialization steps;
12. The app is running.

Comment: This also works for non-embedded web application, which don't need `main()` method, but extends `org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer`, and marked by `@SpringBootApplication`. Then `SpringServletContainerInitializer` will scan for it, thus the application class is instantiated & invoked on deployment. `@SpringBootApplication` itself is also marked by `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, thus from here, it's the same story as in the answer.

Comment: I am getting issue with starting of embedded jetty server. I am getting this error when i am running the application -> Failed startup of context o.s.b.w.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@3982206a{application,/,[org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyServletWebServerFactory$LoaderHidingResource@3e9fb485],UNAVAILABLE}","logger":"org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext","throwable":{"class":"java.lang.IllegalStateException","msg":"Multiple servlets map to path /: dispatcherServlet[mapped:JAVAX_API:null],connectionPoolServlet[mapped:JAVAX_API:null]" . I am using OpenJDK11

Answer (score 3):

When you look for something Spring Boot does during auto-configuration, you should look in the `*AutoConfiguration` classes. In this case, `DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration`.

Comment: If `DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration` did the job, then who trigger it to execute?

Comment: I don't know the details around exactly how things work in Spring Boot, but I know that inside the `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure` artifact there's a `META-INF/spring.factories` file that contains a list of all the default `*AutoConfiguration` classes. Beyond that I can't say more than "the framework does it." You can have a look into how the `EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation works. It imports `EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector`, which might have something to do with exactly how the auto-configuration classes are detected.

Comment: Probably it has something to do with `SpringBootServletInitializer` - an implementation of `WebApplicationInitializer`, which make use servlet-3.0 feature `ServletContainerInitializer`. The link in question talked about this. But the spring code has become so complex, especially with annotations, it had to find the whole picture without reading through the code carefully.

Comment: It's not linked directly to `ServletContainerInitializer`. The `DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration` is on the list of `*AutoConfiguration` classes that Spring Boot considers during context initialization. The fact that `DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration` kicks into action rather than being ignored is because Spring Boot detects that the application context is a web application context (see the `@ConditionalOnWebApplication` annotation.) You can have `DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration` kick in without a `SpringBootServletInitializer` too. In fact, embedded servlets only have a main-method.

Comment: Thomas Kåsene's answer gives a more detailed story, maybe you are also interested.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to deploy the Spring Boot application as a traditional WAR, then the [Servlet 3.0 specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Service%20Provider) details how service providers can set it up so that the 3.0 compliant servlet container will automatically bootstrap any web assets (Servlet, Filter, ServletContextInitializer's) into the servlet container. The "magic" is accomplished in the spring-web dependency. If you un'jar it, you'll find file "spring-web/META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer". Open the file and you'll see single line "org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer". This class delegates to all classes that implement [WebApplicationInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html), more specifically their onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) method. There's one such concrete class I'm aware of in Spring Boot, namely [SpringBootServletInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/support/SpringBootServletInitializer.html).