# When does onRefresh method of DispatcherServlet gets called?

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets

When does onRefresh method of DispatcherServlet gets called?

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39214547/2985643

Answer (score 1):

```
DispatcherServlet extends FrameworkServlet
FrameworkServlet extends HttpServletBean
HttpServletBean extends HttpServlet
```

- HttpServletBean overrides init() method of GenericServlet in that method it calls initServletBean() method which is overridden by FrameworkServlet
- in that initServletBean() method of FrameworkServlet it calls initWebApplicationContext() method
- in that method it checks whether the webApplicationContext is instance of ConfigurableWebApplicationContext
- if it is, it calls configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext() method
- in that it calls refresh method on webApplicationContext
- see the implementation of refresh() method in AbstractApplicationContext at last it calls finishRefresh() method
- in that method it publishes ContextRefreshedEvent
- in FrameworkServlet there is private class ContextRefreshListener which implements ApplicationListener
- the onApplicationEvent() method on this class calls FrameworkServlet's onApplicationEvent() method
- in that method it calls onRefresh method which is overridden by DispatcherServlet